# How can I break a tie in the result of a sum using a date?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called **referrals**, which contains the following columns:

`id | campaign | module | team | referred | referred_by | createdAt`

To obtain the rank, I tried to sum the unique occurrences of `referred_by`, and then rank them. This seemed to work up to a point, however, when there was a tie I found that the rank would repeat. What I need instead is to also account for the date in which the referral happened (the earliest date should be ranked first, breaking the tie).

**Here's an example of my original query:**

```
SELECT referral.referred_by AS id,
          SUM(1) AS referral_count,
          RANK() OVER (ORDER BY referral.count DESC) AS current_position

  FROM referral

  WHERE referral.campaign = 106 AND
        referral.team = 36 AND
        DATE_PART('month', referral."createdAt") = DATE_PART('month', NOW()) AND
        DATE_PART('year', referral."createdAt") = DATE_PART('year', NOW())

  GROUP BY referral.referred_by
  ORDER BY referral_count DESC LIMIT 20

SELECT date_trunc(r."createdAt"), r.referred_by, count(*)
```

**Which yields:**

```
id  |   referral_count  |   current_position

894 |   3               |   1

895 |   2               |   2

896 |   2               |   2

897 |   1               |   4
```

**And it should ideally be:**

```
id  |   referral_count  |   current_position

894 |   3               |   1

895 |   2               |   2

896 |   2               |   3

897 |   1               |   4
```

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add the created_at to your ordering

```
SELECT referral.referred_by AS id,
          SUM(1) AS referral_count,
          RANK() OVER (ORDER BY referral.count DESC,referral."createdAt") AS current_position

  FROM referral

  WHERE referral.campaign = 106 AND
        referral.team = 36 AND
        DATE_PART('month', referral."createdAt") = DATE_PART('month', NOW()) AND
        DATE_PART('year', referral."createdAt") = DATE_PART('year', NOW())

  GROUP BY referral.referred_by
  ORDER BY referral_count DESC LIMIT 20

SELECT date_trunc(r."createdAt"), r.referred_by, count(*)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using CTE you can have an explicit intermedaite step

```
with score as (
    SELECT
        referral.referred_by AS id,
        SUM(1) AS referral_count,
        min(referral.createdAt) as min createdAt    
    FROM
        referral
    WHERE
        referral.campaign = 106 AND
        referral.team = 36 AND
        DATE_PART('month', referral."createdAt") = DATE_PART('month', NOW()) AND
        DATE_PART('year', referral."createdAt") = DATE_PART('year', NOW())
    GROUP BY
        referral.referred_by
)
SELECT
    id,
    RANK() OVER (
        ORDER BY
            referral_count DESC,
            createdAt     DESC
    ) AS current_position
FROM
    score
```

Comment: will this work properly - ordering by referral."createdAt" ?

Comment: indent - the question is - will it rank by createdAt? I don't think your code will. it will give unique rank numbers but not as specified. please also see my answer to see what i mean.

Comment: Yes, you can order by createdAt (asc or desc) after the count

Comment: Sorry I have read to fast the question ;-). You don't need row_number (if same count and same date ==> you wan't the same rank ?)

Comment: Thank you all for your answers.

Indent: It's unlikely that the date will be exactly the same, but in that case I think row_number would useful to break the tie.